# Removing dynamic controls from panel not working

Tags: c#

After this "foreach" done, there is still buttons into panelGroups.Controls

```
foreach (Button button in panelGroups.Controls)
{
    panelGroups.Controls.Remove(button);
}
```

Debug mode in Visual Studio:
[image: Debug mode in Visual Studio]

Comment: I'm sure this throws an `InvalidOperationException` because you change the enumeration (`Controls`) that you are currently iterating (`foreach`) through. And if you have any `Control` inside that panel that are no `Button` and not inherited from `Button`, you will get an `InvalidCastException`, too.

Comment: Well, I used "panelGroups.Controls.Clear();" and it's works, In this case I have only buttons and I have to remove any of the controls so that good for me, But maybe for other case it's will be not useful.

Comment: So see my answer, should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The code you show is very error prone:

1. If there is a `Control` in your `panelGroups.Controls` that is no `Button` and not inherited from `Button`, your code will throw an `InvalidCastException`. That is because you try to cast every `Control` in that panel into a `Button`, which will fail for example for a `Label`
2. You try to change an enumeration (by calling `Remove`) *while* you are iterating through it. This causes an `InvalidOperationException`.

You better try it that way:

```
foreach(Button button in panelGroups.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList())
    panelGroups.Controls.Remove(button);
```

By using `OfType<Button>()` you select only the controls from the panel that really *are* `Button`.
By calling `ToList()` you complete that iteration to select the buttons from `Controls` before starting the iteration over the resulting `Button` set.

This way you would avoid the exceptions and your code should work.

**Note** however that this only works for `Button`s that are directly contained in your `panelGroups`. If you have other containers (like panels or groupboxes) inside that panel that contain more buttons, these buttons are not enumerated this way. You would have to recurse down through the containers and remove these buttons from the containers' `Controls` collection.